# java.lang.IllegalStateException FragmentManager is already executing transactions

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to run my application and getting the error I have as the title. I can't understand why I am getting these as it seemed to be working earlier.

The runtime error I get is below, can't see why it is not working can somebody help me 
Errors:

```
Process: com.example.blogapplication, PID: 22891
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:2207)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2267)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:814)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope.lambda$onFragmentActivityStopCallOnce$1(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.0:179)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6904)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope.onFragmentActivityStopCallOnce(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.0:163)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope.bind(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.0:191)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.addSnapshotListenerInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.0:923)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.0:883)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.0:824)
        at com.example.blogapplication.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:80)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at com.example.blogapplication.Menu.onStart(Menu.java:131)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1425)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7825)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22891 SIG: 9
Process 22891 terminated.
```

Home Fragment

```
  Query firstQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(3);
            firstQuery.addSnapshotListener(getActivity(), new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {

                        if (isFirstPageFirstLoad) {

                            lastVisible = documentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(documentSnapshots.size() - 1);
                            blog_list.clear();

                        }

                        for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                                String blogPostId = doc.getDocument().getId();
                                BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class).withId(blogPostId);

                                if (isFirstPageFirstLoad) {

                                    blog_list.add(blogPost);

                                } else {

                                    blog_list.add(0, blogPost);

                                }


                                blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        }
```

Menu

```
private void initializeFragment(){

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, homeFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, notificationFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, accountFragment);

        fragmentTransaction.hide(notificationFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.hide(accountFragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, Fragment currentFragment){

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if(fragment == homeFragment){

            fragmentTransaction.hide(accountFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(notificationFragment);

        }

        if(fragment == accountFragment){

            fragmentTransaction.hide(homeFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(notificationFragment);

        }

        if(fragment == notificationFragment){

            fragmentTransaction.hide(homeFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(accountFragment);

        }
        fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

}
```

Comment: what is written in HomeFragment line 80 please

Comment: firstQuery.addSnapshotListener(getActivity(), new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

Comment: can you post the code inside the question ?

Comment: I have it is the first piece of code, do you need the whole class?